# Markov chain to predict banking frauds

Tags: complex-event-processing

I want to develop a system for detecting and preventing bank transactions fraud using complex events processing. Ive been researching and looks like markov chain could help me with this.
What are the general steps and data flow to develop such system?
Im not looking for complete answers, just the generic steps, so i can research and obtain my own answers.

Given this scenario what exactly can i predict with markov chain?

I know its not a specific question but im not looking for specific answers

Comment: *"I know its not a specific question but im not looking for specific answers"* ...which makes this question off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

you need full insight into all possible parameters and their dependencies. For every parameter, you will require one dimension, and the calculations will become rather big. there are other algorithms that are much simpler and more elegant.

Markov chains are more suited for fever parameters. For scenarios like this you should try other methods like "Support vector machines".

Also have a look intomore elegant solutions like Benford's Law